# How can I hide the password used by OpenSSL in my history log?

Tags: php, linux, security, bash, openssl

I am using OpenSSL to encrypt files on my server.

The command I am using is similar to this one:

```
 openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt \ -out file.enc -pass pass:mySillyPassword
```

My worry is that the password will be saved in the logs of my server.

What is the best way to encrypt my files with OpenSSL without having the password saved on the server logs?

**IMPORTANT** I am executing this command via PHP. The the command is stored in a shell script file. That PHP just executes.

**UPDATE**
I am generating different keys for each file encrypted.

Comment: I would store it in an environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use php-oopenssl.. instead, http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php .  Also, using a shell script is very vulnerable.  Anyone might see the password from ps -ax command or similar.

Assuming that ONLY ROOT can see the password, the password (that too encrypted ideally by 2nd-hardcoded password) should be read from a root:root owned file with 0600 chmod options.  The web-server when starts as a root, will have access rights to that file.  The server can set that file content (i.e the password) as an env-variable for php files into some global variable.  I had tried something like that long time ago & it worked.

-Trilok.

Comment: Running a web-server with root privileges is the doing of desperados.

Comment: @sam, many people still use root to start apache server, and then it turns to apache/nobody as effictive user once fully started.   Anyway, root was an example here..it can be apache/apache etc, but in those cases file should be owned by apache (or whichever is euid).

Comment: Ah, OK. Then you'd indeed need to set an env var or something to get that working.

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way to encrypt files? Because when you encrypt a file with PHP, when you finally decrypt it you have to set a header and Content-Type. No? Here is a small PHP script that I though of using but it seems that you need to set a Content-Type when you decrypt: https://gist.github.com/1384192

Comment: I m sorry, but don't understand why heaer/content-type has anything to do with security/encryption?

Comment: About methods, I think it should be sufficient & 110% better than running a command-line openssl from a bash/shell within php.  Theoritically, the MOST secure way would be to enter a passphrase from a terminal in non-echo mode (invisible) mode (assuming no keylogger is there), since key-files are also prone to be hacked.  Even when used as a non-admin user on windows 7 also, a private-key file is subject to being accessed by a malware.  Pls. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The way I had implemented in apache was using a separate directory-hierarchy for php-scripts using sensitive password.  The apache server  only used to set the password in a global or Env-var if the request is for that sensitive directroy.  PHP files in that directory should be root:root 0644, so no other user can modify it.  (Assuming root is always non-compromized).  The password was stored in /var/php/.../pas.inc file readbable/owned by only root.  Since apache starts as a root, it could read from the file using a directive (if path matched to sensitive-data url, then include it).

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the password in an OpenSSL configuration file.

http://wwwneu.secit.at/web/documentation/openssl/openssl_cnf.html

Comment: I am generating different keys for each file encrypted.

Comment: Generate a temporary .cnf file from a template.

Comment: So what is better a key file or a .cnf file?